# Safari ignore media query portrait

Tags: css, responsive-design, safari, media-queries

I am testing my code on different browsers. I see that Safari (version 9 on Mac) absolutely ignoring media query on orientation portrait.

This is a code:

```
@media print  and  (orientation:landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
  // Hide the default headers and footers that the browser adds

  .no-print-portrait {
    display: block;
  }
  .portrait-notification {
    display:none;
  }
}

// If the orientation is in portrait it hides all html and displays a notification to the user to switch to landscape

@media print  and  (orientation:portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){

 // Hide the default headers and footers that the browser adds
  @page {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .no-print-portrait {
    display: none;
  }

  .portrait-notification {
    display: block !important;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Does somebody has idea why?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Safari doesn't support that due to the documentation

```
http://caniuse.com/#search=print
and/or
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page
```

Comment: I don't think it is "*due*" to the documentation, but rather "*according*" to it ;-)